# The name of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a qustion about WPF.  Below are 2 pieces of code. The first is for a windows form application and works. The second is for a WPF application and doesn't work.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

1. `public WpfLogger(String fileName, Form form, TextBox textBox)`
2. `public WpfLogger(String fileName, Wpf wpf, TextBox textBox)`

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: There is no `Wpf` class.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't nearly enough information about what you're seeing, and you haven't provided enough code either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: When you say it doesn't work do you mean that it rips a hole in space time and sucks everything in around it creating a singulatity? Or do you mean you get an error.

Comment: Replace `Wpf wpf` with `Window window`.

Comment: or `Window form` to keep the same names

Comment: @SLaks can you tell me how i have to do it then?

Comment: @Alex That would be really mean though.

Comment: @AMR Than we could be looking at a compiler issue in the future, because this question might have been asked several billion years from now.

Comment: @The_Unknown: How to do _what_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no class by the name of `Wpf`. If you're looking for the equivalent of

`System.Windows.Forms.Form`, that would be `System.Windows.Window`.

By the way, WPF is a complex framework in and of itself (not suitable for the unexperienced), I suggest you learn the basics of C# and OOP by practicing with some Console Applications first.